# Register a SCDF task with yaml file configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a local implementation of a SCDF server and the task that I want to register uses a yaml file to populate a map, like this:

```
aplication:
    mapValues:
        value1:
            foo: bar
            bar: foo
        value2:
            foo: bar
            bar: foo
```

If I execute this project from my IDE the autowired object is correctly populated with the values defined on my yaml file. If I register the application and try to execute from the SCDF dashboard, I get a NullPointerException when I try to use the autowired object since the registered app is not populating the object with the values from the yaml file.

My question is: how do I avoid this from happening? How do I tell a registered task to use the values from an yaml file? Is there an specific step in which I tell the application to use the yaml file, like during the mvn package or during the app registration using the SCDF shell? Is there an option to set the app yaml file before executing the task on the SCDF dashboard?

Any help with this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The task being executed is a Spring Boot application. If that application includes an `application.properties|yml` (eg. in `src/main/resources`) those properties will be available to the task.

For a sanity test you can add a very simple property in application.yml such as

```yaml
foo: bar
```

then in your main class something like this:

```
@Value("${foo:UNKNOWN}")
private String fooValue;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
   System.out.println("***** " + fooValue);
}
```

What do you see when you run the app directly in IDEA? And what about when you run the app from Dataflow UI?